# Не получается добавить перевод для определенных строк Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, строки

Хочу добавить переводы на другой язык  через Translations Editor. Так получается что студия их не хочет принимать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезагружал студию, перестраивал проект, удалял и добавлял эту локаль, но почему-то эти строки не хотят переводится. То есть ввести я могу но ничего в таблице не остается, и если несколько раз ввести в одну ячейку перевод, то получается в файле strings.xml такое например:

```
<string name="job_type_fulltime">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="data_loading_subtitle">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="data_loading_title">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_full_part_time">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_fulltime">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_parttime">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_full_part_time">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="data_loading_title">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_full_part_time">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_fulltime">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="job_type_parttime">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="data_loading_title">A tiempo completo</string>
<string name="data_loading_subtitle">1</string>
<string name="data_loading_subtitle">1</string>
```

Не могу понять что не так и как исправить. Может локаль не ту взял или еще где-то натупил?

Comment: Очень глючный инструмент - сколько не пробовал использовать, всегда косяки и всё равно приходилось разгребать вручную в текстовом режиме. По-моему его перетащили из ADT для Eclipse и забыли что он есть.

Comment: @woesss, я уже понял это)) просто думал может я что-то не то делаю, но вообще глючить начало на 5 языке, до этого все было ровно и красиво :)

Comment: скорее всего влезает какой-то спец символ

Comment: @Style-7, спецсимволов нету, проверял :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно решение не совсем верное, но мне помогло. Для того чтобы студия не ругалась и все приняла, вручную прописать в xml файле нужные вам переводы и дальше после перезагрузки IDE с очисткой кеша у вас все приживется нормально. Это конечно немного напрягает, но будем надеяться что в следующих обновлениях все починят.